# rsync on OS X changes folder's group name to _lpoperator

Tags: mac-osx, rsync

Here is how to demo the problem:

1. Grab Terminal on OSX, and run

   ```
   cd ~ && mkdir abc && ls -l ~/
   ```

   Here is the output about folder "abc":

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x   2 justin  staff    68 Jan  4 20:20 abc
   ```

   The group name can be seen as "staff".
2. rsync a file or folder from remote server to the folder "abc":

   ```
   rsync -aP -v -z -h username@server:/mnt/foo/ ~/abc/
   ```
3. check the group name of the folder "abc" again:

   ```
   $ ls -l ~/
   drwxr-xr-x   2 justin  _lpoperator    68B Jan  4 19:44 abc
   ```

   and all the files in "abc", the group names are _lpoperator.  Try to create a file in "abc" and check its group name,

   ```
   $ touch def
   $ ls -l ~/abc
   -rw-r--r--  1 justin  _lpoperator  0 Jan  4 20:28 def
   ```

I know when i use -a option for rsync, it will try to keep the permission for that remote file, but why _lpoperator was created? it's really weird, any idea?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you are using the `-a` option to rsync.  One setting that '-a' turns on is '-g', preserve group.  The folder or file you are transferring from the remote machine is owned by group id (gid) 100.  On your machine, gid 100 is '_lpoperator'.  You can verify this by running`grep _lpoperator /etc/group`.  That will show the actual group id of 100.

So, when rsync does the transfer, it preserves the gid from the remote file.  That gid maps to the _lpoperator group on your machine, so you see that the group changes when you run 'ls'.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but I have a minor correction: on OS X, /etc/group doesn't necessarily have correct info; the actual data is in /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups (which only root has permissions to read directly). Instead, use something like `dscl /Search -read /Groups/_lpoperator` or `dseditgroup -o read _lpoperator`. In either case, they'll tell you its GID is 100 (but they'll call it the "PrimaryGroupID").

Comment: OH yeah, good point.  A lot of OSX config is not in the traditional unix files.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is the exact answer to my question.